# Sum totals when using Calculated Members

Tags: ssas, mdx, calculated-columns

In my SSAS cube (multidimensional) I have a measure group called Cargo. In there I have three properties:

```
[Contract_Key] (integer)
[Include In Sum] (integer)
[Quantity] (integer)
```

My Contract_Key points to my dimension Contract. Include In Sum is either 0 or 1. Quantity is a number I want to sum, if Include In Sum = 1.

My Contract dimension contains a Contract Number as well as a sub contract number. Very often my users want to group the contracts by their main contract numbers but still be able to see the individual sub contract details. Unfortunately when having both the main contract (which contains the total quantity) and the sub-contracts will add up a wrong number in the Quantity (the will double up).

So I have added a Calculated Member (for now called Summed Quantity) where the expression is:

```
IIF([Measures].[Include In Sum]=1,[Measures].[Quantity],0)
```

Being very new to MDX, my assumption is that if Include In Sum equals 1 then it will sum the Quantity and otherwise it will have the value 0.

My Contracts are all in the same dimension but there can be main contracts and sub-contracts. The way my Include In Sum is made is:

```
If there is only a main contract, then Include In Sum is true for the main contract.
If there are sub-contracts then set the main contract's Include In Sum to 0 and all the sub-contracts Include In Sum to 1.
```

My goal is to always show a quantity - either from the main contract or from the sub-contracts (which have more correct values, if they exists). My Include In Calc shows correctly in Excel - and are thereby set correct in my database.

My problem is that if a contract consist of sub-contracts, then I do see the correct values on the individual lines (main contract is blank in quantity and all sub-contracts shows the correct quantities). But my sub totals and grand totals in Excel are blank. Only main contracts which have no sub-contracts shows up correctly.

```
Contract No    Quantity    Include In Sum
100            34000       1      <==== A sub-total line - only a main contract
   100         34000       1
110                        4      <==== A sub-total line - main contract with sub-contracts
   110                     0
   110-1       2500        1 
   110-2       2500        1
   110-3       2500        1
   110-4       2500        1
```

Of course I do not want to show the "Include In Sum" - it is just there as long as I cannot get the sub totals to work in Excel.

What I want is that my second sub-total line should give me the value 10000.

My expression does not contain a SUM function (which might be the problem). But when adding the SUM() around the above MDX expression will just make every value come out as #VALUE in Excel - again - this might be me not knowing the syntax!

Comment: Okay - found a simple solution... I simply just multiplied my Include In Sum with Quanity!
But IF I had to use other criterias (like "where quanity > 1000") it would be nice to learn how to.

Comment: And then again - it doesn't add up correctly! Have made my solution in SQL instead :-/
Need to read and learn MDX properly!